# Recurring payments in facebook messenger possible? (native)

Tags: facebook, stripe-payments, messenger

Facebook recently launched messenger payments in beta (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/buy-button))

This leverages either Stripe or Paypal on the backend. I know bot allow recurring payments to be made directly via their API.

Question: Does Facebook's implementation/integration with these payment providers allow native recurring payment to be made?